# Request chega null no C#

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, request

Tenho uma request que está sendo feita desta forma no angular 5.

```
enviarEmail(titulo: TitulosCobranca, unidade: UnidadeEmpresa) {
    let param: any = {
      titulo: titulo,
      unidade: unidade
    }

    return this.http.post(this.UrlService + '/TitulosCobranca/envio', param)
      .map((res: any) => res.data);
}
```

No C# estou tentando receber os dados da seguinte forma:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route(*_minhaRota_*)]
public async Task<IActionResult> EnviarEmail([FromBody] ParametrosPesquisaViewModel param)
{
    UnidadesEmpresaViewModel unidadeEmpresa = param.unidade;
    TitulosCobrancaViewModel titulo = param.titulo;
    /* Continue ... */
```

Quando eu coloco o *breakpoint* e vou averiguar o que está acontecendo o valor de `param` está *null*.

Colocando o `console.log` antes da requisição os dados estão lá.

Abaixo print do corpo da requisição:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
 public class ParametrosPesquisaViewModel
    {
        public int Index { get; set; } = 1;

        public string Search { get; set; } = "";

        public string Order { get; set; } = "";

        public string razaoSocial { get; set; }

        public string cnpj { get; set; }

        public string telefone { get; set; }

        public int pagina { get; set; }

        public int nrRegistros { get; set; }

        public ParamConsultaViewModel Param { get; set; }

        public UnidadesEmpresaViewModel unidade { get; set; }

        public TitulosCobrancaViewModel titulo { get; set; }
    }
```

Acima está o meu Model.

Alguém tem uma luz para me dar?

Comment: Uma sugestão... nas ferramentas de desenvolvedor do navegador, tem uma sessão para ver os dados que são enviados. No Chrome é a aba network. Verifica o corpo da requisição lá - **e se possível, edite o post para incluir o corpo da requisição, do jeito que aparece nessa aba**. Se as informações estiverem ausentes no corpo, o problema é no Angular. Se estiverem presentes, o problema é no C#.

Comment: Sim, os dados estão presentes Renan. Eu já havia verificado isto também. Adicionei um print com o corpo da requisição.

Comment: Eu nunca trabalhei com Angular... Ao fazer a requisição "na unha" com Ajax, se eu informava o tipo da requisição (*contentType*) como *application/json*, a informação só chegava no lado .NET se o corpo fosse JSON válido. Eu vejo que o corpo da sua requisição não é JSON, então eu sugiro, a título de teste, fazer algo assim: return `this.http.post(this.UrlService + '/TitulosCobranca/envio', JSON.stringify(param)).map((res: any) => res.data);`

Comment: A requisição está como JSON já Renan. eu acabei cortando a imagem mas o tipo da requisição é application/json e na pré-visualização que eu fui ele trás desta forma. Mas os dados estão como JSON como sugerido.

Comment: E a sua `ParametrosPesquisaViewModel ` possui um `UnidadesEmpresaViewModel unidade` e um `TitulosCobrancaViewModel  titulo`?

Comment: Nos mostre a sua rota, no controller, acredito que o problema seja a rota.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Adicionei o meu model para vocês visualizarem.

Comment: @RodrigoK.B meu controller está ali  


`[HttpPost]
 [Route("/api/TitulosCobranca/envio/")]
public async Task<IActionResult> EnviarEmail([FromBody] ParametrosPesquisaViewModel param)
{
    UnidadesEmpresaViewModel unidadeEmpresa = param.unidade;
    TitulosCobrancaViewModel titulo = param.titulo;`

O erro estoura logo quando tento acessar param.unidade, por isso não adicionei o que está embaixo dele.

Comment: @RodrigoK.B  minha request não tem o /api pois já tenho a variável declarada na minha super classe.... 
`protected UrlService: string = "http://localhost:57512/api/";  `

Comment: ok, aparentemente o problema é que o objeto param, quando você passa ele no post, não foi convertido em json. Acredito que se você converter, irá funcionar.

Comment: não sei como funciona no angular5 para esse tipo de conversão, mas vi exemplso no angular2 do pessoal usando `JSON.stringify(product) `, que é o que eu uso no angularjs

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77687/discussion-between-lucas-brogni-and-rodrigo-k-b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema realizando a requisição com um objeto próprio montando ele na requisição apenas com os campos que fossem de meu interesse, capturar no back-end,  no caso sem passar o objeto completo.

```
enviarEmail(titulo: TitulosCobranca, unidade: UnidadeEmpresa) {
    let param: Object = {
        "Titulo": {
            id: titulo.id
        }, 
        "Unidade": {
            id: unidade.id,
            email: unidade.Email
        } 
    }

    return this.http.post(this.UrlService + 'TitulosCobranca/envio', param)
        .map((res: any) => res.data);
}
```